# How to repeat Excel solver in several rows using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

So it's a pretty standard VBA request (found something sort of like it search stack overflow, but not quite).

I have a basic solver equation that I'd like to resolve, but need to do so for 100 rows in a single column. I'm trying to get solver to:

1. Target cell S5 to value = 1
2. By changing cell T5
3. Output this in U5
4. Do this all the way down with target S6, change T6, output U6; S7, T7, and U7... etc. to S100, T100, and U100.

It's a simple function but I can't seem to get it to work. Right now the code (pasted at the end) outputs the solution for S5 to T5 all the way down column U. So it just reiterates the S5 to T5 solution in U5, U6, U7, etc.

If someone could help--I think it's just a minor tweak?--I'd really appreciate it!

```html
Sub macrorepeatsolve()

Dim myR
Dim c
Set myR = Range("T5", "T100")
For Each c In myR
    SolverOk SetCell:="S5", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="T5"
    SolverSolve userfinish:=True
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cells(5, "T").Value

Next
End Sub
```

Sorry for being an idiot! Would appreciate any help!

Best, 
S.

Comment: use `c.row` instead of hardcoding 5 everywhere

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Sub macrorepeatsolve()

Dim count as Integer
Set count=5
Do While count<=100
    SolverOk SetCell:=Sheets("sheetname").Cells(count,19), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=Sheets("sheetname").Cells(count,20)
    SolverSolve userfinish:=True
    Sheets("sheetname").Cells(count,21).Value = Sheets("sheetname").Cells(count,20).Value
    count=count+1
Loop
End Sub
```

Try using something more like this. In this format, the varible `count` will allow you to dynamically change the cells being affected

Comment: hmmm, that format is definitely better. But the code doesn't seem to run in reference to my selection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having it not run in reference to your selection. Do you mean that it doesn't run in reference to S5,T5,U5 or that it doesn't go off from your current selection? (Though I suppose that the point is moot considering chancea gave you advice that seemed to solve your problem :P)